# JavaScript: получить значение через addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Есть такой HTML блок, где input скрыт с помощью стилей, а `label` представляет из себя кнопку(http://viralpatel.net/blogs/css-radio-button-checkbox-background/):

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="20" value="20">
<label for="20">20</label>
```

Мне нужно по нажатию у `input` получить значение `value="20"`

На JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){

console.log(e.target)
});
```

В консоли выводятся два события по клику мыши, одно принадлежит `<label>`, другое `<input>`, Если написать console.log(e.target.value), то у `label` это будет `undefined`, у `input` = 20.

Не думаю, что это правильно. Как лучше получить  значение `value` только для  `input`, не затрагивая `label` (без jQuery)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Вы неправильно используете атрибут `for` для `label`. Он должен быть равен `id` связанного с ним `input`.
2. Вы ставите `addEventListener` не на определенный элемент, а на весь документ.

Кликните на цифру и внизу появится значение.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("name_id");
input.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log(input.value);
});
```

```css
input { display: none; }
```

```html
<input id="name_id" type="radio" name="type" value="20">
<label for="name_id">20</label>
```

Полезные ссылки:
[webref.ru label](https://webref.ru/html/label)
[MDN EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: А если таких инпутов много?